# bash sequence 00 01 ... 10

Tags: bash

in bash, with

```
$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I can get a numbers sequence, but in some case I need

```
01 02 03 ... 10
```

how I can get this ?

and how I can get ?

```
001 002 ... 010 011 .. 100
```

Comment: Wow my first reflex when I saw the title was, what's with the dots? There's no missing numbers, it's `00`, `01`, `10`, `11` etc.

Comment: TL/DR: Older versions of `bash` do not respect 0-prefixed number in brace-expansion. Use `seq -f '%07.0f' 999999 1000001` which should be available on all but allegedly-ancient `bash` versions. YMMV with `seq -w 99 101` which may flake out on scientific-notation numbers above 999999.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This will work in any shell on a machine that has `coreutils` installed (thanks commenters for correcting me):

```
seq -w 1 10
```

and

```
seq -w 1 100
```

Explanation:

- the option `-w` will:

> Equalize the widths of all numbers by padding with zeros as necessary.

- `seq [-w] [-f format] [-s string] [-t string] [first [incr]] last`

> prints a sequence of numbers, one per line (default), from
> first (default 1), to near last as possible, in increments of incr (default
> 1).  When first is larger than last the default incr is -1

Comment: Well, any shell that has access to `seq`, which is non-standard.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I'm yet to see a unix-like OS where `seq` ain't present. You know any?

Comment: seq is not part of the shell, but external tooling (eg. coreutils).

Comment: `seq` is not available on OS X.

Comment: @favoretti FreeBSD (and likely the other BSDs) doesn't have seq. They have jot

Comment: @WilliamPursell: `[36][22:36:27] vlazarenko@alluminium (~) > uname -a` : 
`Darwin alluminium 12.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.0.0: Sun Jun 24 23:00:16 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.7.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`,
`[37][22:36:28] vlazarenko@alluminium (~) > seq` :
`usage: seq [-w] [-f format] [-s string] [-t string] [first [incr]] last`

Comment: @nos: `seq` _comes_ from BSD :)

Comment: @favoretti if so, they've removed it on freebsd. (though it's in the sysutils/coreutils port). The OSX man page mentions it originated in Plan 9

Comment: That is good to know that Apple is finally shipping `seq`.  Its absence was an annoyance.

Comment: @favoretti no `seq` on Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0. glad to see it on the newer release

Comment: @pb2q: Ok, thanks for the info. @nos: same to you. I was diluted by assumption that `coreutils` are standard everywhere these days.

Comment: I couldn't leave it ;) Installed FreeBSD 9.0 just now in a VM and it _does_ have `seq` installed by default :)

Comment: Solaris doesn't know about seq either.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I altered my solution indicating that machine in question needs to have `coreutils` installed.

Answer (score 21):

use seq command with `-f` parameter, try:

`seq -f "%02g" 0 10`

results:
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10

`seq -f "%03g" 0 10`

results:
000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010

Comment: The results may be slightly surprising, with the wrong input parameters:
`seq -f%07g 999999 1000000` yields 0999999 and 001e+06.

Comment: Hi, @Caesar, in this case, you need to give another precision parameter, please try: `seq -f%07.7g 999999 1000000`

Comment: @Caesar could also use `$ seq -f '%07.0f' 999999 1000001` to get 0-prefixed non-scientific notation.

Answer (score 17):

```
printf "%02d " {1..10} ; echo
```

Output:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
```

Similarly:

```
printf "%03d " {1..100} ; echo
```

---

In more recent versions of bash, simply:

```
echo {01..10}
```

And:

```
echo {001..100}
```

Comment: echo {01..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: bash 3.2.48 evaluates the expression as JuanPablo lists.

Answer (score 6):

```
for i in {01..99}; do
  echo $i
done
```

will return :

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
...
```

Replacing 01 with 001 and 99 with 999 or 100 will do what you expect also.

Comment: This answer adds no new info to what has already been discussed in other answers and comments. Older versions of `bash`such as `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)` on my MacOS 10.13.6 do not respect 0-prefixed number in brace-expansion.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ printf "%02d " {0..10}; echo
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 
$ printf "%03d " {0..100}; echo
000 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 011 012 013 014 015 016 017 018 019 020 021 022 023 024 025 026 027 028 029 030 031 032 033 034 035 036 037 038 039 040 041 042 043 044 045 046 047 048 049 050 051 052 053 054 055 056 057 058 059 060 061 062 063 064 065 066 067 068 069 070 071 072 073 074 075 076 077 078 079 080 081 082 083 084 085 086 087 088 089 090 091 092 093 094 095 096 097 098 099 100
```

Just vary the field width in the format string (2 and 3 in this case) and of course the brace expansion range. The `echo` is there just for cosmetic purposes, since the format string does not contain a newline itself.

`printf` is a shell builtin, but you likely also have a version from coreutils installed, which can be used in-place.

Comment: Don't understand how One "%02d" in FORMAT string is applied to *all* printf arguments?

Comment: I guess you're confused by the c version — think of it like `printf` does an internal loop over those arguments, just like the awk solution posted in other answers.

Answer (score 5):

awk only:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (i=0; i<10; i++) printf("%02d ", i) }'
```

Comment: Don't need awk: `for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do printf "%02d " $i; done` -- that's valid bash.

Answer (score 4):

The following will work in bash

```
echo {01..10}
```

**EDIT seeing the answers around me I just wanted to add this, in the case we're talking about commands that will work under any terminal

```
yes | head -n 100 | awk '{printf( "%03d ", NR )}'   ##for 001...100
```

or

```
yes | head -n 10 | awk '{printf( "%03d ", NR )}'    ##for 01..10
```

Comment: $ echo {01..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 4):

There are so many ways to do this!  My personal favorite is:

```
yes | grep y | sed 100q | awk '{printf( "%03d ", NR )}'; echo
```

Clearly, neither the `sed` nor the `grep` are necessary (the `grep` being far more trivial, since if you omit the `sed` you need to change the `awk`), but they contribute to the overall satisfaction of the solution!  The final `echo` is not really necessary either, but it's always nice to have a trailing newline.

Another nice option is:

```
yes | nl -ba | tr ' ' 0 | sed 100q | cut -b 4-6
```

Or (less absurdly):

```
yes '' | sed ${top-100}q | nl -ba -w ${width-3} -n rz
```

Comment: You win an extra bonus for making easy things complicated. But that's what computers are for ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
echo 0{0..9}
```

You can get: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09

```
echo 0{0..9} 1{0..9}
```

You can get: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19

```
echo 00{0..9} 0{10..99}
```

You can get 001 .. 099

Answer (score 3):

as commented by favoretti, `seq` is your friend.

But there is a caveat:

`seq -w` uses the second argument to set the format it will use.

Thus, the command `seq -w 1 9` will print the sequence `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

To print the sequence 01 .. 09 you need to do the following:

`seq -w 1 09`

Or for clarities sake use the same format on both ends, for instance:

`seq -w 000 010`  for the series 001 002 003 ... 010

And you can also use a step argument that also works in reverse:

`seq -w 10 -1 01'  for 10,09,08...01  or`seq -w 01 2 10` for 01,03,05,07,09