# Bash "if number in array" also considers partial matches. How to solve this?

Tags: bash

I have written the following bash code:

```
NStep=25
NTotal=435
Redone=('375' '400' '425' 'last')
for i in $(seq 0 $NStep $NTotal)
do
    if [[ "${Redone[@]}" =~ "$i" ]]; then
        echo "do something"
    else
        echo "do something else"
    fi
done
```

However, for steps `0`, `25` and `75`, it enters the `if` statement (and does something), whereas I want it to enter the else statement (and do something else). How can I make my regex more specific or rewrite the if statement?

Thank you

Comment: Why regex? Why not use equality operations to look for an exact match?

Comment: Because then I have to add an additional loop.

Comment: This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891162/bash-sequence-00-01-10) Add `-w` to `seq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, the regex doesn't have to match the whole string. You need to say the number should be wrapped by spaces or the string's beginning or end:

```
if [[ "${Redone[@]}" =~ (^| )"$i"( |$) ]]; then
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question that suggests that the word could be surrounded by spaces.

Comment: @Barmar: That's how [@] indexed arrays are expanded in =~ regex match. I don't see it documented in `man bash`, though. Also, it's not a general solution, as the array can contain `'375 400'` as single element.

Comment: I misread the code and thought it was looping over the array elements, not matching the entire array at once.

Answer (score 1):

Use an associative array, not an indexed array. (Also, don't use `seq`; use a C-style for loop instead.)

```
NStep=25
NTotal=435
declare -A Redone=([375]= [400]= [425]= [last]=)
for ((i=0; i<= $NTotal; i+=$NStep))
do
    if [[ -v Redone[$i] ]]; then
        echo "do something"
    else
        echo "do something else"
    fi
done
```

The keys of the associative array act like a set, and `-v` (which here tests if a given key exists in the array) acts as the membership operator.

---

For versions of `bash` that don't allow you to use `-v` with indexed array names (4.2 or earlier), you can fall back to checking if the expansion is unset.

```
if [[ "${Redone[$i]+x}" = x ]]
```

Since you used the null string as the value for each, `${Redone[$i]+x}` will only expand to `x` when `$i` is a key in the array.

Comment: Your workaround works for me (I'm using GNU bash , version 4.2.46(2)release). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regex matching leads to partial matches, I prefer a more concrete solution.

```
NStep=25
NTotal=435
Redone=('375' '400' '425' 'last')
for i in $(seq 0 $NStep $NTotal)
do
  isPresent=0  
  for redone in "${Redone[@]}"
  do
    if [ "${redone}" = "${i}" ]
    then
      isPresent=1
      break
    fi
  done
  if [[ "${isPresent}" -eq "1" ]]; then
        echo "do something"
    else
        echo "do something else"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check if an element is contained in an array:

```
NStep=25
NTotal=435
Redone=('375' '400' '425' 'last')
for i in $(seq 0 $NStep $NTotal)
do
    if printf "%s\0" "${Redone[@]}" | grep -F -x -q -z "$i"; then
    # or if printf "%s\n" "${Redone[@]}" | grep -F -x -q "$i";
        echo "do something"
    else
        echo "do something else"
    fi
done
```

But I think it would be simpler to just filter elements you are not interested in:

```
comm -12 <(printf "%s\n" "${Redone[@]}" | sort) <(seq 0 "$NStep" "$NTotal" | sort)
# outputs 375 400 425
```

Or you could use `join` and number the lines in `seq` and resort them and do some replacing:

```
# this will print 15 lines of 'do something else'
# and 3 lines with 'do something'
# exactly the same as the `for i in ...` loop above
join -22 -a2 -e "do something else" -o2.1,1.1 <(printf "%s\n" "${Redone[@]}" | sort) <(seq 0 $NStep $NTotal | nl -w1 | sort -k2) |
sort -n -k1 |
cut -d' ' -f2- |
sed 's/[0-9]\+/do something/'
```